# Could not open input file: spark

Tags: php, composer-php, codeigniter-4

I use PHP v8.1 and I'm trying to open Codeigniter (v4.2.10) welcome page using the command: `php spark serve` and I get this error: `Could not open input file: spark`.

I've searched the internet and couldn't find anything related. So I tried to install spark by using composer as : `composer require sparkphp/spark` but no luck. I got the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires sparkphp/spark ^0.16.3 -> satisfiable by sparkphp/spark[0.16.3].
    - sparkphp/spark 0.16.3 requires destrukt/destrukt ^0.7.1 -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require sparkphp/spark:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require sparkphp/spark:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

Now I don't have any idea what should I do and I appreciate any help.

Comment: `sparkphp/spark` looks like it's been removed. I don't see it on GitHub anymore, and packagist says it's been abandoned

Comment: Where did you obtain the information to require `sparkphp/spark` from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Could not open input file: spark
```

means that you are not in the Codeigniter root directory.
just go to Codeigniter root directory then run the command.
if you use composer to create the app

```
composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter project-root
```

just go to the 'project-root' (any name you wrote)

```
cd project-root
php spark serve
```

Comment: creating a new project does not help people who have existing projects and want to use `php spark` in it

Comment: It didnt, it says if you use composer to create app. What I mean if you execute like the syntax/command to create the project, then open the project directory and execute it from there...

Comment: I meant you should include the pre requisite  that you should have codeigniter 4 installed as it does not work on ci version <4